# How to build and deploy different jars and place them in different machines

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I had a project requirement come up where a Jenkins job had to build multiple jars in a same project and want to deploy into multiple machines.
For example I had 5 jars namely 1,2,3,4,5 and deploy into 3 machines namely A,B,C and I can choose where 1,2 goto A machine 3 will goto B machine and 4,5 will goto machine C. And the jars and machine selection is dynamic where any jar can goto any machine. Is there a way to do this.

Comment: You will need to add plugins.  This should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031415/jenkins-how-to-make-single-job-build-and-deploy-on-two-servers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins: How to make single job build and deploy on two servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031415/jenkins-how-to-make-single-job-build-and-deploy-on-two-servers)

Comment: thnx guys for the answer